# how to get sum of dropdown value on each change

Tags: javascript

I want to sum of dropdown value on each change. I want to sum of selected experience value. This is my code. Please anyone help me

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selects = $('select[name^=exp_year]');
    selects.change(function () {
        var value = 0;
        selects.each(function () {
            value += +this.value;
        });
        alert(value);
        $('#dis').val(value);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="exp_year[]" id="exp_year" class="form-control">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option></select> 
<div id="dis"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are searching for:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = 0;
    $('#exp_year').change(function () {
        value += parseInt(this.value);
        alert(value);
        $('#dis').text(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Initialize the variable `value` outside the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do define `var value = 0;` above `var selects = $('select[name^=exp_year]');` and Change `$('#dis').val(value);` to `$('#dis').text(value);`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = 0;
    var selects = $('select[name^=exp_year]');
    selects.change(function () {
        
        selects.each(function () {
            value += +this.value;
        });
        alert(value);
        $('#dis').text(value);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="exp_year[]" id="exp_year" class="form-control">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option></select> 
<div id="dis"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, there were couple of issues with your code. You have value variable inside the change function, you need to have it outside and second you are setting the `$('#dis').val(value);` instead set `$('#dis').html(value);` Check the code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = 0;
    var selects = $('select[name^=exp_year]');
    selects.change(function () {

        selects.each(function () {
            value += +this.value;
        });
        alert(value);
        $('#dis').html(value);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="exp_year[]" id="exp_year" class="form-control">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option></select> 
<div id="dis"></div>
```